# Custom validation: returning ValidationResult(true, null) still fails validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I'm entering a value that passes my custom validation check, yet WPF still comes up with a fail message:

[image]

Validation code parses the percentage, converts to a double. Using the debugger, I can step through and everything works fine. For a value of "50 %" it parses 0.5, steps through and gets to the last line `return new ValidationResult(true, null);`

However, it still causes a failed validation, with a default message "Value '50 %' could not be converted.".

```
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        double valueToValidate = 0;

        try
        {
            string trimmed = (value as string).TrimEnd(new char[] { '%', ' ' });
            valueToValidate = Double.Parse(trimmed) / 100;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
        }

        if ((valueToValidate < Min) || (valueToValidate > Max))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
              "Please enter a value in the range: " + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
```

**xaml:**

```
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Width="45">
                            <TextBox.Text>
                                <Binding Path="AppController.Zoom" StringFormat="{}{0:P0}">
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <helpers:MinMaxPercentageValidationRule Min="0.4" Max="2"/>
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Text>
                        </TextBox>
```

The failure states work fine, prompting with the appropriate message. It just seems to be the

Comment: What does `value` contain when the method is called? `double.Parse("50 %");` should be failing.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I'm an idiot. I accidentally pasted my plain double min-max validator. I've updated it to the percentage one (it trims spaces and % before parsing), then divides by 100. The valueToValidate is 0.5 stepping through it, after parsing, and it passes all checks and reaches return new ValidationResult(true, null);

Comment: Try this: `return ValidationResult.Success;`

Comment: @erikscandola That did the trick! ValidationResult.Success didn't exist, but there was ValidationResult.ValidResult, which did the trick. Thanks, didn't  think to look for a static object but it makes sense. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it in case anyone else comes across this (probably likely, given I followed the MSDN example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Framework:

```
return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
```

In .NET Core:

```
return ValidationResult.Success;
```